# Launch multiple apps in a single command in OS X

Tags: macos, launcher

Is there a way on the mac (os x 10.6) to launch multiple apps in a single command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think using Applescript would be the best way. First open up your AppleScript Editor.app then type in the following:

```
tell application "Mail" to activate
tell application "iCal" to activate
```

Of course that's just a show of concept, customise it as you see fit. Then save it as an application. Now you can either double click it to launch all your applications or use a launcher like Quicksilver or Launchbar.

Comment: I'd like a bit of software that allows you to group software and launch them all, like a launchy type thing

Comment: Hah, that why the activate didn't work, I forgot the quotes

Comment: Each `activate` command blocks the script until the application has finished opening. `open -a iTunes` or `tell app "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Applications/iTunes.app"` wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal you could do:

```
open -a TextEdit ; open -a Safari
```

To open both TextEdit and Safari, or same with Applescript:

```
do shell script "open -a TextEdit"

do shell script "open -a Safari"
```

You can then save the Applescript as an App you can click on.

Or you could use launcher application like Launchpad, Another Launcher or Quicksilver.

Comment: to make this perfect, I would need to know how to launch terminal to the focusses finder window, resize and reposition windows and hide finder dock

Answer (score 2):

I decided to look on how to run multiple applications and I found out that you have to split it – for example

```
tell application "Calculator"
tell application "Calculator"   
    run
end tell
```

wouldn't work, so it took me a little bit but then it hit me so then I did this to make it work:

```
tell application "Calculator"
    run     
end tell

tell application "Calculator"
    run
end tell
```

and it worked.

Comment: Or just `tell app "Calculator" to run` in one line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but it's super simple using Automator on Mac. Just add as many "Launch application" steps as needed and save the process as an App. I keep my app on the desktop to launch OBS, zoom, and the NDI plugin to get ready to stream.

Comment: This was indeed very easy to do and I didn't have to install anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like a bit of software that allows you to group software and launch them all, like a launchy type thing

[Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) is a launchy comparable tool. I think comma separated multiple invocations/commands. (e.g. `A,M,S` for Adium, Mail, Safari)

Comment: Quicksilver is dead, try Alfred instead http://www.alfredapp.com/ (not that I know if it allows groupings)

Comment: @Lo'oris thanks for the info, I've been using Launchbar for the past year or so, and only recently started to evaluate Alfred.

Comment: For current releases of quicksilver see http://www.qsapp.com

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Multiple Launcher](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/Multiple-Launcher-Download-5982.html).

> Multiple Launcher X is an Mac OS X-native application allowing users
>   to create a stand-alone launcher that can open multiple items, both
>   files and folders. Multiple Launcher X also allow users to create
>   aliases to open documents from customized applications, for example,
>   you can ask Preview to open the Photoshop documents. The editor fully
>   supports drag&drop feature.

Answer (score 1):

Alfred Powerpack users can [launch groups of apps with one command.](http://www.cultofmac.com/132934/5-awesome-things-you-can-do-with-alfred-on-your-mac/)

If you prefer a free version use jon2512chua's answer and create an Applescript.

```
tell application "Sparrow" to activate
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
```

Then save it as an application and as run only.  Then use Alfred to launch it with one command just like any other application.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question and your comments to answers are not quite the same thing.

You might consider looking at [ReLaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/index.html), to launch groups of applications.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com), you can launch multiple apps at once.

For example, if you set all your development apps with Spotlight Comments "devapps", you'd then launch Alfred, type "devapps" then use the hotkey for "Action all visible results" (set it in General > Results prefs) and all apps would open at once.

Handy!

Answer (score 0):

```
nano start.sh
open /Applications/app1.app/
open /Applications/app2.app/

exit

then sudo chmod a+x start.sh

later on from CLI:

./start.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 2014 (https://blog.obdev.at/the-sixth-sense/) Launchbar supports quicksilver's *comma trick* which is here called staging or multiple selection or the sixth sense.

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke Launchbar
- Enter `text` for Textedit.app
- Press <kbd>,</kbd> to add current object to the staging area
- Enter `calendar` for Calendar.app
- Press <kbd>,</kbd> + <kbd>↩︎</kbd> to open both apps.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to accomplish this is to:

1. Create a folder (on your desktop is fine).
2. Drag the applications you want to start at one time from the /Applications folder to this new folder. By default, Finder will create a shortcut to each application and *not* actually move it.
3. Select all of the shortcuts in your folder with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open them all at the same time.